# Not able to find <worklightServerRootURL>

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am not able find the  tag under my application-descriptor.xml file. Can anyone suggest how to add As I need change my root url .

Answer (score 0):

The `worklightServerRootURL` is no longer in use starting Worklight 6.0 (you probably upgraded from an earlier release).

If you need to build your app and point it to a different server than the local development server, you do this by right-click on the application folder and selecting Run As > Build Settings and Deploy Target.

Read more about it, here: [The Build Settings and Deploy Target command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_building_and_deploying_build_settings_deploy_target.html).

Comment: This is my scenario I am making connectOnStartup:false in the initoptions.js file.once the IMC connectivity is done i will wl.client.connect() but the app is not connecting to the worklight server

Comment: That's got nothing to do then with worklightServerRootURL?!

Comment: I need to configure the IMC server url in the worklightserverRootURL. as per the procedure

Comment: No, you don't. There is no such element anymore. You follow the steps I have mentioned. That is the URL that will be used when your app then connects.

Comment: I have already added that in the build and deploy . the URL and the context path has been already specified there in the build settings and deploy target. but the app is not connecting

Comment: Then you need to make sure you're using the right address, the right context, that nothing blocks you, etc...

Comment: from the firebug it is showing Host is not responsive.

Comment: in that case it should give me error at beginning but the intial IMC connectivity is succeed and after that when the app tries to connect to worklight server I am getting this error